# Stacking different types of arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having difficulties in stacking different "types" of numpy arrays.

array_1 is `array([(3,111),(3,222)])`

array_2 is `array([(4,111),(4,222)])`

array_3 is `array([[5,111],[5,222]])`

(notice the change in brackets in array_3).

I can easily use `np.hstack` to combine array_1 and array_2, but how can I also combine array_3?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are the types of these arrays??

Comment: The first two are `numpy.ndarray`, the third is a list.

Comment: You're saying `array([[5,111],[5,222]])` is a list?

Comment: yes, but I can turn it into an ndarray by using `np.array(array_3)`

Comment: How could it possibly be a list? Why does your example show the (presumably) numpy array constructor around it? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, it is not a list, but an `ndarray`

Comment: What's the `dtype`.  The () indicate that 2 are structured arrays (and 1d), the 3rd is 2d numeric,

Comment: Also, what `dtype` do you expect for the result.  Structured arrays can only be concatenated with arrays of matching `dtype`.

Answer (score 0):

convert every array to numpy array and then use np.hstack

```
array_1 = np.array([(3,111),(3,222)])

array_2 = np.array([(4,111),(4,222)])

array_3 = np.array([[5,111],[5,222]])

np.hstack((array_1,array_2,array_3))
```

I got the following output

> array([[  3, 111,   4, 111,   5, 111],
>          [  3, 222,   4, 222,   5, 222]])

Comment: look at your `array_1`.  Does it match the question display?